# Is it ok to allocate a UIView twice and am I releasing it properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I wish to create multiple instances of UIView so i figured instead of creating new variables i'd allocate one UIView and then reallocate it again to create another UIView. Is this ok? Plus am I releasing the view properly or is the retain count of tempview is 2 after 2 allocations and a release just brings the retain count to 1?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

UIView *tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];

[array addObject:tempView];

tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];

[array addObject:tempView];

[tempview release];

[array release];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to release tempView before you re-assign it or else it will leak.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
UIView *tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
[array addObject:tempView];
[tempView release]; //you need this to avoid leaking at the next line

tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
[array addObject:tempView];
[tempview release];
[array release];
```

Alternately, you could autorelease tempView each time you alloc/init it, but it's better to release when you can and only use autorelease when you have to.

Comment: is this still the same case with ARC?

Comment: @jeroldov Remove the releases and ARC should work fine.

Comment: I see. I am a bit worried about my UIViewController having many UIViews that I add as menus that might produce memory leak when not in use. I guess it is automatically handled in ARC.

Answer (score 0):

also, if all views you create have the same frame you might do the same in a loop:

```
const int kViewCount = 8;

NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kViewCount];

for(int i = 0; i < kViewCount; ++i)
{
    UIView *tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
    [array addObject:tempView];
    [tempView release];
}
```

just set kViewCount to the number of views you need to create

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that's kinda obvious :) The memory management on the other hand isn't always as straight forward.

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm just not aware of what your background is )